# CSS3 Scaling Animated Background Image Sprites

Tags: html, css, animation, sprite

So I've got a `stick_man` and he likes to run:

```
.stick_man {
    -webkit-animation: walk-cycle 1s steps(8) infinite;
    background: url(http://rmorochove.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/player-running-spritesheet9x81.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    height: 343px;
    width: 198px;
    margin: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes walk-cycle {  
  0% {background-position: 0 0; } 
  100% {background-position: 0 -2719px; } 
}
```

[See Stickman Run Here!](http://jsfiddle.net/TLEpW/)

[Vendor-Prefix Friendly Version](http://jsfiddle.net/TLEpW/1/)

The `stick_man` enjoys running at fixed pixels (look at how happy he looks!). Unfortunately, he's not so happy running responsively.

What I want is to be able scale the image via percentages and have the animation be just as fluid as the above example where we use fixed pixels.

I've tried:

- Messing around with `background-size` (using percentages instead of pixels)
- Messing around with the `background-position` (using percentages instead of pixels)
- Tossing `stick_man` into a container and then varying the container size

Other than that just been playing around with height, width, background-size, and background-position to see if I can get the golden ratio, but so far no luck.

[Here's an example of a failed attempt!](http://jsfiddle.net/nMD7y/)

Please provide a CSS3 answer. I will accept answers using some JavaScript (adding classes and whatnot), but I'm looking for a solution using purely CSS3 animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a big gotcha here exposed by this predicament. Apparently, when using CSS3 `steps` and a percentage `background-position`, the final step is cut-off and not shown.

The only documentation I could find elsewhere on the web describing this was [Rachel Nabor's codepen](http://codepen.io/rachelnabors/pen/zeFqy)

So accounting for this extra frame being cut off, I set the final keyframe to a `background-position` of `112.5%` (8 steps, so add one extra step at the end).

It appears this has fixed the issue. With a little fiddling around, I should have my viable solution:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nMD7y/2/)